# Rails and foundation 5 subnav: active subnav based on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following index based on the Foundation5 framework, 
and I'd like to use the F5 subnav to sort the index:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:tag].present? 
      @posts = Post.includes(:tags, :user).tagged_with(params[:tag]).page(params[:page])
    elsif params[:sort] == 'votes'
      @posts = Post.order("cached_votes_up DESC").includes(:tags, :user).page(params[:page])
    elsif params[:query] == 'unauthored'
      @posts = Post.includes(:tags, :user).where("author_id IS ?", nil).order("created_at ASC").page(params[:page])
    elsif params[:query] == 'hot'
      @posts = Post.includes(:tags, :user).tagged_with(:hot).order("created_at ASC").page(params[:page])
    else
      @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC").includes(:tags, :user).page(params[:page]) 
    end
  end
```

**view**

```
        <dl class="sub-nav right">
          <dd class="active"><%= link_to 'newest', questions_path %></dd>
          <dd><a href="#"><%= link_to 'votes', questions_path(:sort => "votes") %></a></dd>
          <dd><a href="#"><%= link_to 'advice', questions_path(query: 'hot') %></a></dd>
          <dd><a href="#"><%= link_to 'unanswered', questions_path(query: 'unauthored') %></a></dd>
        </dl>
```

In short, clicking on the subnav links leads me to the index page with a query string passed in like so: 
`/posts/?query=hot`
`/posts/?query=unauthored`
`/posts/?sort=votes`

**Question** is, how do I dynamically assign the 'active' class to the **dd** element based on query strings?

I'm using the following helper for another subnav based on path:

```
  def subnav_link(link_text, link_path)
    class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : ''

    content_tag(:dd, :class => class_name) do
      link_to link_text, link_path
    end
  end
```

but I can't figure out how to modify it for query strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've basically answered my own question without even realizing it! Here's how it works:

1. Controller remains the same.
2. Helper remains the same. current_page?(link_path) takes into account the additional params as well.
3. View:

   ```
   <%= subnav_link 'newest', questions_path(:sort => 'newest') %>
   <%= subnav_link 'votes', questions_path(:sort => 'votes') %>
   <%= subnav_link 'unauthored', questions_path(query: 'unauthored') %>
   <%= subnav_link 'unanswered', questions_path(query: 'hot') %>
   ```